# Do I need to override hashCode when using a Set with a Hibernate many-to-many relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, set, hashcode

If I have a many-to-many relationship with Hibernate, and both sides store the collection in a Set, and the Set is initialized to a HashSet, do I need to override hashCode for the types stored in the Set?

My gut says no, since Hibernate would replace my initial HashSet with its own Set. Is this sometimes/always/never correct?

Comment: i always override equals and hashCode

Comment: Even with that, `Set` by default uses `equals` and `hashCode` at least that you provide a `Comparator` (like `SortedSet`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should override `hashCode()` and also `equals()` cause it's a set , and to don't break the contract.  `SortedSet` use comparable instead . [overriding equals and hashCode in hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode)

Comment: You mean [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) and [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is an implementation of it.

Comment: Thanks, and for the Hibernate doc link as well!

Comment: if someone would be so kind to take a look at my question, i would be so glad, because i can't make a many-to-many update work. thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24737145/equals-and-hashcode-of-these-entities-spring-mvc-hibernate